# Nested IF AND OR in Excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

How do I write the formula for the following:

```
if B2 = "SF" and D2 = "1"
    then H2 = E2 + .75
else if B2 = "SF" and D2 = ".25"
    then H2 = E2 + .625
else if B2 = "CW" and D2 = "1"
    then H2 = E2 + 1
```

I want my answers to be in `H2`, with data being entered into `B2`, `D2` and `E2`.

Comment: Stick this in `H2`: `=if(AND(b2="sf", d2=1), E2+.75, If(AND(b2="sf", D2=.25), E2+.625, If(AND(B2="CW", D2=1), E2+1, "")))`

Comment: Alternatively: `=IF(B2="SF", IF(D2=1, E2+.75, IF(D2=.25, E2+.625, "")), IF(AND(B2="CW",D2=1), E2+1, ""))`

Comment: Alternatively `=(B2="SF")*(D2=1)*(E2+.75) + (B2="SF")*(D2=.25)*(E2+.625) + (B2="CW")*(D2=1)*(E2+1)`

Answer (score 0):

=if(AND(B2="SF",D2=1)=TRUE,E2+0.75,if(AND(B2="SF",D2=0.25)=TRUE,E2+0.625,if(AND(B2="CW",D2=1)=TRUE,E2+1,0)))

Regards